# How to get strings from a text file to array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to read a list of strings from a text file and put that into an array with n words.If instead of all the lines of text I need only the first two, I would make my array of size 2 and set n = 2. However when I pass the number of words in as an argument I receive a segmentation fault, if n is not equal to the number of words in the list, and the entire list will still print. How can I control how many words my array will hold while keeping track of my next string in the list?

My text file looks like this: 
AH12M8 N\n
AD34FU O\n
APD83H O\n
LKFU29 N\n

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    FILE *myfile;
    myfile = fopen("Test.txt", "r");
    char *numWords;
    long n = strtol(argv[1], &numWords, 10);

    if(argc != 2)
   {
        printf("Too Few Arguments");
   }
   else
   {
        char arr[n][100];
        int i = 0;
        while(fgets(arr[i],sizeof(arr),myfile)!=NULL)
        {
            arr[i][strlen(arr[i])-1] = '\0';
            i++;
        }
        int total = i;
        for(i = 0; i < total; ++i)
        {
           printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
        }
        fclose(myfile);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One problem is you check if you have enough arguments *after* you use argv[1].

Comment: Where is 'frame' defined?

Comment: "char arr[n][100];" is wrong way of allocating memory. you should dynamically allocate memory using malloc or calloc.

Comment: @NaveenKumar Why is it wrong ?

Comment: Oh ok, I will do that. I think the problem is I am not understanding how to correctly allocate each string to the array. arr[n][100]- Here n = the number of words and 100 is the length of each word, right? So by changing n shouldn't I be able to decide how many words I read from the file?

Comment: @Ironcode you are allocating array size based on user input.  read  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/143858/array-or-malloc

Comment: Thank You Naveen. I have made the change in my code but that doesn't solve my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that you only allocate space for `n` strings, but then you read the entire file -- so if there are more than `n` lines, you run off the end of your array and corrupt memory and likely crash.  Another problem is that you're giving `fgets` the length of the ENTIRE array, not the length of a single string, so if any lines are longer than 99 characters, you run off into then next line (or off the end and crash).  Fixing both problems is relatively easy:

```
    char arr[n][100];
    int i = 0;
    while(i < n && fgets(arr[i], sizeof(arr[i]), myfile) != NULL)
    {
        if (arr[i][strlen(arr[i])-1) == '\n')
            arr[i][strlen(arr[i])-1] = '\0';
        i++;
    }
```

I also changed it to only drop the last character if it is a newline -- if you have any input lines longer than 99 characters, they'll be split into multiple lines.

Comment: Thank You I have been trying to figure this out for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

```
 while(fscanf(myfile,"%[^\n]%*c",arr[i])==1)    
    {
        arr[i][strlen(arr[i])-1] = '\0';
        i++;
    }
```

And check value of `argc` before using `argv[1]` .

Comment: The entire list still prints even after making that change :/

Comment: @IronCode  I don't get what you mean by that. You want to print that line by line ?

Comment: So if my list has 3 strings each separated by \n, e.g:

ADM8U N\n
FJ29JD O\n
AL9UJ2 N\n 
38HDS1 N\n
 I only want the array to hold the first two, I would want to enter 2 as an argument.

Comment: @IronCode I have modified . Please take a look .

Comment: Is there a way for me to only get my array to read the first two or a certain number of lines from the file by specifying n?

Comment: @IronCode  Then try putting `n` in `fgets` instead of `sizeof(arr)` .

Comment: That just results in a segmentation fault :/

Comment: @IronCode Hmm , I assumed . Did you try `fscanf` ?

Comment: Yes I did, still the same problem. Another alternative I thought of was to save each string to a temp variable and just put the value of that variable in arr[i], but I don't even know how I would go about doing that...